# Python - Check if all elements in a list satisfy an inequality

Tags: python, list, inequality

I have a list `T = [[2,5],[4,7],[8,6],[34,74],[32,35],[24,7],[12,5],[0,34]]`, and i want to check if all elements in each embedded list within T satisfy an inequality.

So far i have:

```
upper = 10
lower = 0
for n in range(len(T)):
    if all(lower < x < upper for x in T):
        'do something'
    else:
        'do something different'
```

So if all elements in each T[n] are between 0 and 10, i want to do something and if else then i want to do something else. In the list above T[0],T[1] and T[2] would satisfy the inequality whereas T[3] would not.

Comment: What's the issue with your code?

Comment: What about the code you've shown doesn't do what you want it to? Can you be clearer about what you want?  Is it confusing to deal with the nested lists?  Would it be sufficient to flatten `T` first?

Comment: @Rohit Jain When i ran the code, the inequality was satisfied every time - so the all() function kept returning true even when the inequality clearly wasn't satisfied.

Comment: @Holtz : I'm guessing the code ran the `else` statement always, even when the `if` statement should have been run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are almost there. Just replace `range(len(T))` with `T` to iterate over the `T` list and check for the nested elements in the if condition, as follows :

```
>>> T = [[2,5],[4,7],[8,6],[34,74],[32,35],[24,7],[12,5],[0,34]]
>>> upper = 10
>>> lower = 0
>>> for elem in T:
        if all(lower < x < upper for x in elem):
            print "True", elem
        else:
            print "False", elem


True [2, 5]
True [4, 7]
True [8, 6]
False [34, 74]
False [32, 35]
False [24, 7]
False [12, 5]
False [0, 34]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid complicated code and go for `numpy`:

```
a = np.array(T)

test = (a>0) & (a<10)
#array([[ True,  True],
#       [ True,  True],
#       [ True,  True],
#       [False, False],
#       [False, False],
#       [False,  True],
#       [False,  True],
#       [False, False]], dtype=bool)

test.all(axis=1)
#array([ True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Which you can reuse as a list calling `test.any(axis=1).tolist()`.

Comment: As long as OP doesn't already use numpy in his program, or the list is huge and speed is an issue, this is very bad advice. Installing an external library for a trivial task like this would be the very definition of overkill, especially if the library has C-extensions which need to be compiled. Adding a dependency should be a well thought-about step, not something you do because it simplifies two lines of code. Of course this is less relevant for small personal throwaway scripts which will only run in one environment, but otherwise dependencies should be kept as small as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I'd also go for numpy:

```
import numpy as np

T = [[2,5],[4,7],[8,6],[34,74],[32,35],[24,7],[12,5],[0,34]]
T = np.array(T)
for t in T:
    if np.all(t>0) & np.all(t<10):
        print t
    else:
        print 'none'

[2 5]
[4 7]
[8 6]
none
none
none
none
none
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also get list of indexes and checked condition with list comprehension:

```
>>> T = [[2,5],[4,7],[8,6],[34,74],[32,35],[24,7],[12,5],[0,34]]
>>> upper = 10
>>> lower = 0
>>> result = [(i, all(lower < x < upper for x in l)) for i, l in enumerate(T)]
[(0, True), (1, True), (2, True), (3, False), (4, False), (5, False), (6, False), (7, False)]
```